# C# - HTTPWebRequest not returning anything

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

So without fiddler open, my code doesnt seem to do ANYTHING!
But with it open, it works fine?! What?

```
HttpWebRequest init = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://accounts.spotify.com/en/login?continue=https:%2F%2Fwww.spotify.com%2Fus%2Faccount%2Foverview%2F");
init.Method = "GET";
init.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36";
init.Timeout = 8000;
HttpWebResponse resp1 = (HttpWebResponse)init.GetResponse();
```

The thread (In my case ThreadPool thread), will just freeze, not end, will just freeze as its not able to connect, and the try catch doesnt even seem to work either.

If I change the Port on Fiddlers Settings to anything other than 8888 and have Fiddler open, it starts to freeze again, meaning somewhere its linked to 8888 somehow. Yet its not referenced in my code at all.

---

**FIXED!

Found out it was caused by not closing! `resp1.close()`.
Thanks everyone!**

Comment: What do you mean by "my code doesnt seem to do ANYTHING" ?

Comment: To see anything in fiddler you usually need to configure proxy via say web.config. If you stop fiddler and not changing config back - your network connections from inside app won't work.

Comment: Basically the thread is just stuck, its not doing a single thing. When I open Fiddler (Which runs under 127.0.0.1:8888) it starts working. I dont even have that as the proxy. Its very very odd.

Answer (score 0):

It's done right that, what you wrote in your code. Try debug this code and see what you get as a response, pay attention to **responseBody** and **HtmlResult**

```
HttpWebRequest init = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://accounts.spotify.com/en/login?continue=https:%2F%2Fwww.spotify.com%2Fus%2Faccount%2Foverview%2F");
init.Method = "GET";
init.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36";
init.Timeout = 8000;
HttpWebResponse resp1 = (HttpWebResponse)init.GetResponse();
HttpStatusCode sc = resp1.StatusCode;
String sd = resp1.StatusDescription;
string HtmlResult = "";
string responseBody = "";
using (System.IO.Stream rspStm = resp1.GetResponseStream())
{
    using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(rspStm))
    {
        HtmlResult = HtmlResult +
                "Response Description: " + resp1.StatusDescription;
        HtmlResult = HtmlResult +
                "Response Status Code: " + resp1.StatusCode;
        HtmlResult = HtmlResult + "\r\n\r\n";
        responseBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```